# Software installation UBuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: permissions

I am just starting with Ubuntu, so I would like to have your help. I am trying to install a software on my notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I did the following procedure:

1. Open a terminal from the folder where I have the software.(Documents)
2. Then in the terminal I typed:

   ```
   cd
   sudo chown -R user:user /opt/
   sudo chown -R user:user /tmp/
   ```
3. Then I go to the folder documents by typing in the same terminal

   ```
   cd Documents/
   ```

   then I enter `./INSTALL`.

And I have an error saying  `permission denied`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing several things wrong. Better to [edit] and post exactly what are you trying to install and what instructions are you trying to follow.

Comment: Where were these instructions from?

Comment: Which software are you trying to install specifically? Why did you change the ownership on `/opt` and `/tmp`? That doesn't sound like a good idea and probably doesn't achieve what you intend. What's the output of `ls -l ~/Documents/INSTALL`?

Comment: I've done a google search for `"sudo chown -R user:user /opt/` and `"sudo chown -R user:user /tmp/"`, and can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have execute permissions on the `./INSTALL` file.

Fix:

```
cd Documents
chmod +x INSTALL
```

Now when you run `./INSTALL` you should have permission to run it.

Comment: Could you click on the tick on this post. It will give both you and me more repuation. Clicking on the tick makes this post the accepted answer.